# Using more pins on connector to satisfy current ratings

Tags: power-supply, current, connector

I have a power brick that is rated at 20v and 12a. I will need connector between two wires, but I as unable to find one that is either not ugly, to much bulky and has a lock system.

I thought to use GX connector, but while it has voltage requirement, it is missing proper current rating, GX12 has rating of 5a/240v.

My question is, if I use GX12 6pin connector and group by 3 will that work. E.g. current goes through 3 pins instead of one. If my logic is correct then that would give me 15a in ideal situation.

Any concerns going this way?
Are there any alternative connectors that support my power supply?

Comment: Is that 5A per pin or for the entire connector?  And under what condition is the connector or pin rated for 5A?  is that the manufacturer's absolute max rating, and at what temperature.

Comment: Might want to look at this discussion:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/564800/stacked-pcb-connections-split-up-current/564851#564851

Comment: @SteveSh I'm pretty sure that is per pin, as the 2 pin connector and 6 pin connector have the same rating and pin diameter stays the same. This is an `Rated current` not max, temps up to 85 C.

Comment: @SteveSh I'm looking at this specifications [GX12 Specs](https://www.elecbee.com/en-1948-gx12-aviation-connector-4pin-plug)

Comment: So then, assume that the 5A/pin is a good number to use.  Then you would be good with (per the referenced discussion) (12A/5A per pin) * 1.25 = 3 pins.  Note that for a hi-rel application, we would take the 5A manufacturer's current rating and derate it by 50% right off the bat.

Comment: @StaveSh Yep, sounds about right. Not sure if laptop charger would fall/require an hi-rel application, probably not? Let me know what you think. On the side note, can you provide answer for this question so I can mark it as Best answer.